# Conditionally rendering component based on routing in react

Tags: reactjs

Hello how i can conditionally rendering my component based on routing?

example of my app.js

```
const App = () => (
    <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          <Col lg="2">
            <Sidebar />
          </Col>
          <Col lg="10">
            <main>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            </main>
          </Col>
        </Row>
    </Container>      
)
```

in this case i want to hide my sidebar component if routing is **/login**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a [`Switch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) which renders nothing for the `/login` route, but renders the `Sidebar` for every other route.

```
const App = () => (
  <Container fluid>
    <Row>
      <Col lg="2">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" />
          <Route path="/" component={Sidebar} />
        </Switch>
      </Col>
      <Col lg="10">
        <main>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
);
```

Comment: Won't the `Col` appear empty when the path is `/login`?

Answer (score 2):

So there are actually a couple of approaches here. I assume you are using `react-router-dom` for extracting `Route` component and you directly render `App` component such as `ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);`

If that is the case, the fastest solution based on your code snippet is that

```
const App = () => {
  const pathname = window.location.pathname
  return (
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          {pathname === '/login' ?
           <Col lg="2">
            <Sidebar />
          </Col> : null}
          <Col lg="10">
            <main>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            </main>
          </Col>
        </Row>
    </Container>)      
}
```

If, you `App` component is used such as `<Route exact path="somePath" component={App} />`

Or, exported after being wrapped by `withRouter` Higher Order Component provided by `react-router-dom`, passing `history`, `location` and `match` props automatically handled by the routing library so you do the following update

```
const App = ({location: {pathname}}) => {
  return (
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          {pathname === '/login' ?
           <Col lg="2">
            <Sidebar />
          </Col> : null}
          <Col lg="10">
            <main>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            </main>
          </Col>
        </Row>
    </Container>)      
}
```

I am assuming that, currently your code works the way you expect and your only concern is rendering `SiderBar` conditionally.

However, when setting up multiple routes, I would suggest utilizing `Switch` component provided by `react-router-dom` https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

Also, instead of dynamically show/display `SideBar` component based on pathname, I would probably create a component such as `MainLayout` in the following way

```
const MainLayout = ({children}) => <div><SideBar/>{children}</div>
```

And update my `Home` component such as

```
const Home = () => <MainLayout>{content related to home page}</MainLayout>
```

So by this way, the `SideBar` would only be visible in the pages that you want it to be visible without checking pathname

Comment: The 'MainLayout' idea was exactly what I needed (but didn't know I was looking for)! Thanks!

Comment: @cagri Wouldn't `MainLayout` always show the `Sidebar` as it is attached to the `MainLayout` component?